# Modeling one-to-many relations using Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design

This question is more of a general question about how to model simple one-to-many relations using collections: should a change in a list item be reflected in the version of the aggregate containing it?

The domain is about **meeting scheduling** (like in Outlook).
I have a **Meeting** entity, which can have multiple **Participants**.
A participant can accept/decline meeting requests.
Rescheduling a meeting nullifies all of the participants confirmations.

I thought of two ways to model this.

**Option 1**
The Meeting aggregate will contain a list of Participants where each Participant has a ParticipantId and a Status (accepted/denied).
The problem here is that every Accept or Deny command, for a specific participant, increments the Meeting's version, which means two participants will enter a race condition if trying to Accept the meeting request based on the same original version.
Although this could be solved by re-reading the Meeting's document and retrying the Accept command, it's quite annoying considering how often this could happen.
Another approach is to ignore the meeting's version when executing the Accept command, but this introduces a new problem: what happens if, after sending the meeting requests, the meeting has been rescheduled?  In this case we can't afford to ignore the Meeting's version, because this time the version DOES represent a real version that should be considered.
BTW, is it at all a good practice to ignore the version in some of the commands and not in others?

**Option 2**
Extract a Participation aggregate out of Meeting.
Participation will have MeetingId, ParticipantId, and Status.
It will also have its own version.
This way, when participant X Accepts the meeting request, only the relevant Participation will be modified, and the rest will be left intact.
And, when rescheduling the meeting, a "Meeting Rescheduled" event will be published and an event handler will respond to it by resetting all of the Participations' statuses to "NotAccepted" regardless of their current version.
On the one hand this sounds logical in the sense that a meeting's version shouldn't be incremented just because someone accepted/denied its request.
On the other hand, modeling Participation as a standalone aggregate doesn't sound quite right to me, because it is has no meaning outside of the context of the meeting.

Anyway, would love to get feedback on this and see the various approaches to this problem.

Comment: Good question, but I think it would be better at [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com)

Comment: If you added the `Participation` aggregate, you would have to check two versions (Participation and Meeting) when accepting a meeting to meet the case of a rescheduled meeting, correct? Might be an additional argument against having this aggregate.

Comment: @user3151902 when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

> Although this could be solved by re-reading the Meeting's document and retrying the Accept command, it's quite annoying considering how often this could happen.

This looks like a modeling error.  You should keep in mind that the meeting aggregate is not the book of record for the participants availability - the real world is.  So the message shouldn't be AcceptInvitation, but instead *InvitationAccepted*.  There shouldn't be a conflict about this, because the domain model doesn't get to veto events outside of its authority boundary.

You might, depending on your implementation, end up with a concurrent modification exception in your plumbing, but that's something that you should be handling automatically (ie: expected version any, or a retry).

> Another approach is to ignore the meeting's version when executing the Accept command, but this introduces a new problem: what happens if, after sending the meeting requests, the meeting has been rescheduled?

The solution here is to model more carefully.  Yes, sometimes you will get a message that accepts or declines an invitation that has expired.

Put another way: [race conditions don't exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/).

> A microsecond difference in timing shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors.

What happens to Alice, who replied instantly to the invitation, when the meeting is rescheduled?  Why wouldn't the same thing happen to Bob, when his reply arrives just after the meeting is rescheduled?

> Participation as a standalone aggregate doesn't sound quite right to me, because it is has no meaning outside of the context of the meeting.

I find that heuristic isn't particularly effective.  It's much more important to understand whether entities can change state independently, or if their changes need to be coordinated.

> Actually, the Meeting aggregate is used to track the participants availability. That's what it purpose is. Unless I didn't fully understand you...

It's a bit subtle, and I didn't spell it out very well.

Suppose the model says that I'm available, but an emergency in the real world calls me away.  What happens?  Am I blocked from going to the hospital because the model says I have to go to a meeting?  Can somebody cancel my emergency by changing the invitation I've submitted?

Furthermore, if I'm away on an emergency, are you available for a meeting that is scheduled for the same time as the meeting you and I were going to have?

In this space, the *real world* is the authority for whether or not somebody is available.  The model is just looking at a cached copy of a message describing whether or not somebody was available in the past.

The cached information being used by the model is not guaranteed to be complete.  See Greg Young on [warehouse systems and exception reports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDW0QWie21s&t=10m48s).

> which makes me think that perhaps the Meeting aggregate should have two version fields: one will be a strong version which, when incremented, represents a breaking change, and another soft version for non-breaking changes. Does this make any sense?

Not really.  *Version* is not, as far as I know, a term taken from the ubiquitous language of scheduling meetings.  It's *meta data*, if it exists at all, and the business rules in your model should not depend upon meta data.

> I agree, but a Meeting ID (or any ID for that matter) is also not part of the ubiquitous language, yet I might pass it back and forth between my domain world and external worlds.

Comment: > You should keep in mind that the meeting aggregate is not the book of record for the participants availability - the real world is.
Actually, the Meeting aggregate is used to track the participants availability. That's what it purpose is.  Unless I didn't fully understand you...
Regardless, I agree that there should probably be a "MeetingRequest" aggregate and a corresponding "RequestAccepted" event sent to the Meeting aggregate.

Comment: > I find that heuristic isn't particularly effective.
A MeetingRequest can be accepted independently of changing parts of the meeting (like name and description), but not with respect to other parts (like date/time and location of meeting), which makes me think that perhaps the Meeting aggregate should have two version fields: one will be a _strong_ version which, when incremented, represents a breaking change, and another _soft_ version for non-breaking changes.
Does this make any sense?